# Number of samples, -5, must be non-negative using panda python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file with date and time. I want to give specific timeinterval (60min) in between time range (start time and end time). I wrote a code with a date. But it gives me an error  Number of samples, -5, must be non-negative. Then I checked with separate csv file with less data. Then I found that I have time like 9:53 , 10:20 ,11:42 .... Then when I'm dividing to find num_periods then its give me an error.
 example
take date range like
2018 /8/6 start time is 6:00
2018/8/6 end time is 23:52
then it between I have time like 7:00, 8:52,10:42 so on. 
after that in next day I have a time period like this.
So when I tried to find a num_periods then it give me this error.
I want to specify time in between this time_range
(start_time+time_interval(3600 in seconds (60min)) in between time_range)
Can anyone give me solution for this?
my code is,

```
time_interval = 3600 
date_array = []
date_array.append(pd.to_datetime(data['date'][0]).date())

start_time = []
end_time   = []

temp_date  = pd.to_datetime(data['date'][0]).date()
start_time.append(pd.to_datetime(data['time'][0], format='%H:%M:%S').time())

for i in range(len(data['date'])):
cur_date = pd.to_datetime(data['date'][i]).date()
if( cur_date > temp_date):
    end_time.append(pd.to_datetime(data['time'][i-1], format='%H:%M:%S').time())
    start_time.append(pd.to_datetime(data['time'][i], format='%H:%M:%S').time())
    date_array.append(cur_date)
    temp_date = cur_date

end_time.append(pd.to_datetime(data['time'][len(data['date'])-1], format='%H:%M:%S').time())
datetime_array = []
for i in range(len(date_array)):
s_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date_array[i],start_time[i])
e_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date_array[i],  end_time[i])

timediff = (e_time - s_time)
num_periods = int(timediff.total_seconds()/time_interval) +1 
time_list = pd.date_range(start=s_time, end = e_time, periods=num_periods ).to_pydatetime()
datetime_array.extend(time_list)
```

error:
[image]

subset of my csv file
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `num_periods` is negative:

```
num_periods = int(timediff.total_seconds()/time_interval) + 1
```

the easiest solution is to take the `abs` value instead:

```
num_periods = abs(int(timediff.total_seconds()/time_interval)) + 1
```

Note: that `date_range` supports ranges in reverse order (where start > end).

Comment: woww.. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much you saved my day. Can you explain little bit why did you use(abs)  for this?

Comment: Yes, abs is the absolute value, so abs(-3) == 3 etc, so if you see "number is non-negative" error this sometimes is the right thing to fix.